# Nuxt.js Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Проблема заключается в том что проект надо перенести на Nuxt и часть кода не работает. А именно от размера экрана надо выполнить не большие манипуляции с текстом.
Так как Nuxt это SSR, то код не может выполниться на стороне сервера так как не знает размер окна.

Можно как-то выполнить эту идею чтоб работало все ?

Ошибка какая появлятся после run generate и переноса на хостинг

```
   [nuxt] Error while initializing app DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.
    at Object.Je [as appendChild]
```

Сам примерный компонент какой работает на Vue, но с nuxt нет.

```
<template>
    <section>
        <div>           
            <h2 class="subtitle" v-html="filterHeadSlogan"></h2>            
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'testapp',
    data() {
      return {
        filterHeadSlogan: '',
        windowWidth: 0
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getWindowWidth(event) {
        this.windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth
        var str = "<i>HELLO WORLD</i>"
        if (this.windowWidth >= 960) {
          this.filterHeadSlogan = str
        } else {
          this.filterHeadSlogan = str.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '')
        }
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWindowWidth);
        //Init
        this.getWindowWidth()
      })
    }

  }
</script>
```